# Creating multiple buttons in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to this. However, I've created a small VBA script in Excel. This script highlights the row the button is on, asks for a name and then inserts today's date and the name entered on to some cells in the row. It's basically used to book out media that is recorded on this spreadsheet.

The issue I have is that I'll need a `CommandButton` for every row, and I have no idea how to get the command button to change the the row values within the script to reflect the row that the button is on. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't you really need only one button and the ability to write the date + name to the next free row?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify your question more clearly, but if I understand your question right, you need to write data in the next empty cell. If that is the case, you can use this:

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Select
    If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

This will search for and select the next empty cell in column B, starting from B10. Hope this helps!